# Need to do a cross reference in Excel

Tags: excel, search

I am needing to check that our Master Schedule is reflecting all physical work that falls into our SOW(Statement of Work).
I have a sheet that does this fairly simply, but I want to make it a simple cut and paste from our Schedule export, and that way it reflects that it is looking at current data vs data from several months ago.

I can handle the date part, but I can't seem to get the logic in my head right for how I should reference the data to double-check compliance.

Each SOW Paragraph has a number assigned to it, and that is what each task would refer to.

| Activity Type | Activity ID | CAM | WBS | OBS | % Complete | SOW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ASAP | 49.3.4.2.3.2.030 | Pam | 77.4.1.2 | C.11.1 | 20% | 1.0 |
| ASAP | C2_4.20.010.011 | Shaun | 77.3.1 | C.5.4.2 | 15% | 3.6.1.2 |
| ASAP | C2_4.20.010.012 | Shaun | 77.3.1 | C.5.4.2 | 0% | 3.6.1.2 |
| ASAP | 69.HP.5.1.2.15.30 | Mark | 77.1.1 | C.11.1 | 50% | 3.2 |
| ASAP | C2_6.1.5.15 | Brett | 77.2.1 | C.3.2.1 | 100% | 5.0 |
| ASAP | C2_2.10.55 | Susan | 77.2.1 | C.5.4.1 | 60% | 6.0 |
| ASAP | 29.3.2.11.1.20 | Eric | 77.4.1 | C.11.1 | 20% | 1.0 |
| ASAP | 1Z.DIL.0025 | Adam | 77.1.1 | C.1.1 | 10% | 1.1.2 |

Say this image is an export from our schedule.
I need to make sure that those SOW numbers are lined up with the full SOW for just the ID numbers with a C2. Below would be the example result.

| SOW Number | In Master Schedule? |
| --- | --- |
| 1.0 | No |
| 1.1 | No |
| 1.1.1 | Yes |
| 1.1.2 | No |
| 1.1.3 | No |
| 3.0 | No |
| 3.2 | No |
| 3.3 | No |
| 3.5 | No |
| 3.6 | No |
| 3.6.1 | No |
| 3.6.1.2 | Yes |
| 4.0 | No |
| 5.0 | Yes |
| 5.1 | No |
| 5.2 | No |
| 6.0 | Yes |

The logic I'm trying to figure out with the formulas is:
If A# is in MS_Tab `$G:$G`, does the ID number start with a `C2`? If Yes, list "Yes" under "In MS?", else list "No"

I tried to do a `VLOOKUP` first and of course, that is incorrect since it only looks for the first instance of the search. Then I thought of doing a `VLOOKUP`paired with an `HLOOKUP`, but that still falls into the same problem. I read I could do Index and Match, but I haven't been able to get the logic to work for me.

*Note: I cannot change the ID's to make my life easier, this is using an excel export from our master schedule.*

Comment: Please try to put input data as well as expected output in table markdown format, you can use the [Table Markdown Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), so people can reproduce the scenario.

Comment: @DavidLeal Added the Markdowns. Thanks for that I didn't know where to go to make it look better than a screen shot.

Comment: Thanks, Trestin13 we would need to understand better the ask now. My understanding the second table is the expected output where SOW number is the input too, correct? What is the logic to match both tables?

Comment: The logic, I would think, is to first see if the SOW number in second table is in the first table. If that is the case, see if the Activity ID starts with a C2. The activities not listed as C2 are old and not needing to be checked.

Comment: I see, what about SOW: `3.6.1.2` it has in table 1 two activities, how we handle this? because one activity could start with `C2` and the other one without it. All this should be clarified in your question. Thanks